# How to set Tool Tip on the each Cell of JavaFX Table Mouse-Over?

Tags: java, tooltip, render, javafx-2, cell

I am new to JavaFX. I have created a `TableView` that looks like the image attached.

I would like to show a tool tip on each cell of the table when I mouse over. I have already set two `CellFactory`; one to display a check-box in the first column and one to display an image in the second column.

So showing Tool Tip must not affect these two rendered columns. Is there any way to show tool tip on each cell of the table on mouse over and that should not affect other individual column cell rendering.

[image: Screenshot of table I'm trying to replicate]

Comment: it is unclear for me what you mean with "hide the rendering". Why should a ToolTip, which is a separate stage, hide a node in a TableView? Can you post a small, self-executable application that shows the issue? Otherwise please rephrase the question.

Comment: Use another cell factory for the rest columns other than 1st and 2nd. In this cell factory add tooltip control to show the cell value.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for reply. I have updated my above question. The issue is - I do not want these two column cell Renderers (check box and image) get affected in showing tool tip because i have seen few examples to show tool tip and in examples they set Cell Factory to Renderer tool tip so if I need to set renderer for each column then the renderer for check box and image may get effected. I am sorry I am new to javafx. In simple I want tool tip on cell.

Comment: @AshishPancholi Cell factories are applied to columns. Every table column has its own cell factory, even if you don't set the default one will be used. As you said you already wrote cell factories for the 1st and 2nd columns. Write one more common cell factory (that contains tooltip) for other columns. Cell factory will only affect the columns that you have set by `column.setCellFactory()`.

Comment: @UlukBiy Thanks. Is there any other way than set a common cell factory to the rest of the column? In future there may be a situation arise where I may need other cell factory to rendering something on column with compulsory tool tip and again I will get into the situation where either work.

Comment: @AshishPancholi AFAIK no. Every custom behavior other than default cell factory, needs custom cell factory. You can use the inheritance for your future needs. For instance write "tooltipable" table cell that extends API table cell. Then write "new featured" table cell that extends that "tooltipable" one.

Comment: @UlukBiy Okay. Thanks a lot to clear all these in details.

Comment: @UlukBiy Maybe one of you should write an answer for this question?

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I did when I needed a tool tip in the cells of a certain column:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");

nameCol.setCellFactory
 (
   column ->
    {
      return new TableCell<Person, String>()
       {
         @Override
         protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
          {
             super.updateItem(item, empty);
             setText( item );
             setTooltip(new Tooltip("Life is short, make most of it..!"));
          }
       };
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tooltip in action]

Here's a generic solution, if anyone is looking for something easy. It follows the same convention as other custom cell factories.

Just make a new class and paste [TooltippedTableCell](https://github.com/TurekBot/TooltippedTableCell/blob/master/src/TooltippedTableCell.java) into it; then set the custom cell factory of your desired column like so:

```
someColumn.setCellFactory(TooltippedTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, however, it needs some adjustments to make it work with non-string cell items. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @rapasoft. Did you try passing in a `StringConverter`; does that not work?

Comment: I just realized that there's method for passing `StringConverter` :). But anyway, I am not able to use `StringConverter` bound to specific type (or type parent), since there are custom instances of items (e.g. number, object, etc.), but I am always able to call `String.valueOf(...)` on them and that's sufficient. At least I hope so, I am JavaFX noob ;)

Answer (score 2):

just create tool tip and install on the node which you want

```
    Cell c = new Cell();
    Tooltip.install(c, new Tooltip("text"));
```